# Abstracting out two lines of code in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, coffeescript, angular-services

I am currently working on refactoring two methods that exist in directives into a service.

This is method one:

```
scope.computeStyle = (component) ->
  elementHash = {}
  if component.element.type == 'table'
    elementHash.height = 600
    if component.height?
      elementHash.height = component.height * 50
  else if component.element.type == 'single_value'
    elementHash.height = 200
    elementHash.width = 800
  return elementHash
```

This is method two:

```
scope.computeStyle = (element, rowComponent) ->
  elementHash = {}
  if element.type == 'table'
    elementHash.height = 600
    if rowComponent?.height?
      elementHash.height = rowComponent.height
  else if element.type == 'single_value'
    elementHash.height = 200
    elementHash.width = 800
  return elementHash
```

They both do the same thing (a little differently). They take an `element/component` (which are objects containing data about an object in my application), checks what type of object they are (in this case, a table or a single value), and applies a height and/or width transformation.

Within my service, this is what I have done:

```
angular = require "angular"

angular.module("myapp.dashboards.layouts").service("DashboardLayoutComputeStyle" ->

  @computeStyle = (componentElement, height) ->
    elementHash = {}
    if componentElement.type == 'table'
      elementHash.height = 600
      if height?
        elementHash.height = height
    else if element.type == 'single_value'
      elementHash.height = 200
      elementHash.width = 800
    return elementHash

  @
)
```

Here's where my question comes in:

I am not sure what to do at this line in my abstracted method:

```
  if height?
    elementHash.height = height
```

In method one, this is what it looks like:

```
    if component.height?
      elementHash.height = component.height * 50
```

In method two, this is what it looks like:

```
    if rowComponent?.height?
      elementHash.height = rowComponent.height
```

I have three constraints to the refactoring of these two lines:

1. I must check whether both `rowComponent` and `height` exist in method two
2. I don't need to check whether `component` exists, but I must check whether `height` exists in method one
3. In method one, I must set the `elementHash,height` to `component.height * 50`, while in method two, I can simply assign `rowComponent.height` to `elementHash.height`

How would I abstract these two lines out?

Answer (score 0):

It's a rather confusing scenario, so I tried breaking it down - please correct me if I got anything wrong about how it should work. i'm working of your two original functions rather than your combined version.

- There are 2 functions, but both of them have one case in common (`single_value`), so in effect we can take this common item out, and we have 3 distinct cases (`single_value`, `table` and `rowComponent`)
- In the second function the element is passed along with thw rowComponent only for the sake of checking the type. So instead I would opt for a second variable which is an optional type argument. If it's not supplied, it will use the type from the element, and it will work just like method 1
- As each top level if statement is based off the type of the element,I've changed it to a more legible case statement

---

```
  @computeStyle = (element, type) ->
    # if no type is supplied, use the element's type
    type ?= element.type
    elementHash = {}
    switch type
      when 'rowComponent'
        elementHash.height = if element?.height?
          rowComponent.height
        else
          600
      when 'table'
        elementHash.height = if component.height? 
          component.height * 50
        else
          600
      when 'single_value'
        elementHash.height = 200
        elementHash.width = 800
    elementHash
```

Now where you previously called method1, you can use `computeStyle(element)`, and where you used method2, you can use `computeStyle(rowComponent, element.type)`

=Edit=
As per OP's comment that there is no type to identify the rowComponent by, I've come up with an alternate solution

---

```
  @computeStyle = (element, rowComponent) ->
    elementHash = {}
    # check the second argument to decide if we have a rowComponent or not
    if element.type is table and rowComponent?
      elementHash.height = if rowComponent.height?
        rowComponent.height
      else
        600
    # otherwise check the first elements type
    else
      switch element.type
        when 'table'
          elementHash.height = if component.height? 
            component.height * 50
          else
            600
        when 'single_value'
          elementHash.height = 200
          elementHash.width = 800
    elementHash
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Let me try it out and get back to you.

Comment: I just tried this, but if I am using the method with the optional input `computerStyle(component)`, it never enters the `rowComponent`'s `when` condition. Do I need a second input that says `'rowComponent'` string literal?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Yes that optional type var is needed unless your `rowComponent` has a type different from `table` or `singleElement` which you could use to distinguish it form the other two.

Comment: Can you tell me why you use the string `'rowComponent'` in the switch? You also use the `rowComponent` object, which isn't declared or is an input.

Comment: I see -- I think you thought `rowComponent` is a `type` as well, which it isn't (this is where the lack of curly braces in Coffeescript can become confusing).

Comment: @theGreenCabbage I was hoping that you could manually pass this `"rowComponent"` string whenever you called the function from a context where you knew it was going to contain a rowComponent, as otherwise you would have to pass in the second parameter anyway. I've added an alternative which was closer to your original functions